# SQL update null values and future date values

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to update the end date null values and future date values using where clause.

I used the below query to retrieve but was unable to get the null values and future end date values.

```
select * from GROUP where EMPLOYEE_ID = 133075 and END_DATE >= sysdate and END_DATE is null;


START DATE   END DATE
04/18/2014  **04/18/2018**
04/18/2014  NULL
04/18/2014  NULL
04/18/2014  03/24/2016
04/18/2014  03/24/2016
04/18/2014  07/07/2016
04/18/2014  NULL
04/18/2014  03/24/2016
12/26/2014  NULL
07/07/2016  07/08/2016
07/08/2016  NULL
```

Comment: `and (END_DATE >= sysdate OR END_DATE is null);`  you need to use an or in ()'s or coalsece end date to sysdate such as `and coalesce(end_Date,trunc(sysdate)) >= sysdate`

Comment: Awesome!! that worked. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just need to switch `and` to `or` and wrap the date logic in ()'s so the OR is inclusive of both/either of those conditions.

should be better if end_date is indexed and easier to read/maintain IMO.

```
SELECT * 
FROM GROUP 
WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = 133075 
  and (END_DATE >= sysdate OR END_DATE is null);
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM GROUP 
WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = 133075 
  and coalesce(END_DATE,Sysdate()) >= sysdate
```

latter shouldn't be as efficient as index on end_date wouldn't be able to be used. but is a different way to handle the nulls.  Not as elegant as it replaces null w/ the current sysdate thus ensuring it's always at least equal when null.

My initial comment is off as you don't want a trunc as it would result in <= not >=  however you could trunc the other side... or just leave them alone as sysdate should = sysdate.